# TypeScript error when destructuring an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to destructure some data in an object and I am getting a `Property XXXX does not exist on type unknown`.  I am using React Router to get some data.

```
  let {decoded, reasonTypes, submissionDetails} = useRouteLoaderData('root')
```

The above code triggers the error. While the below code has no problems.

```
  let data = useRouteLoaderData('root')
```

`decoded`, `reasonTypes`, `submissionDetails` are all properties that exist on the data object.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The second code block "works" in that it doesn't give you an error. Yet, `data.decoded` would still report the same error. Narrow the type that you get, or if you're ***really*** sure, use a type assertion. `useRouteLoaderData` might also have a generic signature allowing you to pass the expected type.

Comment: The ts doc mention a nasty workaround for deconstructing. First `type ABC = { a: number; b: number; c: number };`, then `function sum({ a, b, c }: ABC) { console.log(a + b + c); }`. Could you test that ? see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#parameter-destructuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing error because, the data return by the `useRouteLoaderData('root')` may not contain the data you destructuring, so you need to use assertion for this.

Example:

```
useLoaderData('root') as [type of the object that will be return];
```

Know more from [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9792#discussion-4700658)

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are trying to get full type safe hook you can checkout discussion on this [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9792)

If you trying to find time saving hack you can try

`let data = useRouteLoaderData<any>('root')`
OR
`let data = useRouteLoaderData('root') as any`